# Pytorch incorrect value of member variable when using Multi-gpu

Tags: variables, pytorch, multi-gpu

Here is a simple class for running in multi-gpu environment. The member variable `self.firstIter` should be `False` after the first iteration.

```py
Class TestNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.firstIter = True #indicates whether it's the first iteration

    def forward(self, input):
        print 'is firstIter: ', self.firstIter #always True!!
        if self.firstIter is True:
            self.firstIter = False
        # do otherthings
```

The code works as expected when using only one gpu.

However when using multi-gpu (i.e. `nn.DataParallel`), the value of `self.firstIter` is always printed as `True`.

**Why does this happen? What is wrong with the code?**

*Using PyTorch version 0.3.1.*

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  DataParallel operates on model replicas, and changes made to replicas (during forward) are not visible outside forward/backward calls if number of divices is large than 1.

Plz refer to https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nonetype-attribute-when-using-dataparallel/11566 for details.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the answer to help the user and not refer to any site. :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have checked the link you gave, but still cannot get the point. Could you please explain more details on "changes made to replicas (during forward) are not visible outside forward/backward calls"? In my understanding, both the print and change of the value of `self.firstIter` happens INSIDE forward call, so why the problem is caused by model replicas?

Comment: In your case, 'firstIter' is created as class attribute. When you instantiate the testnetwork and call forward with two different gpus, it works like following: 

In iter 1, each gpu replicates the instance created in the main process and makes a forward call. After printing 'True', the 'firstIter' is set to be false on each gpu as expected, BUT, it only happens on the replicas exisiting on each gpu and the edditing on attribute will not be recorded for the instance created in main process (pytorch mechanism). So, in iter 2, each gpu would start from 'firstIter=True' again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @HarryChow, thanks a lot for your explanation! So I understand the mistake I make in my original codes is the way to print `firstIter`. If I can access the 'replicas on each GPU' and print `firstIter` therein, it should work as expected, correct? Then another question follows: how can I access the replica on each GPU? Thanks!